# Why is it needed to set `pam_loginuid` to its `optional` value with docker?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

In order to run ssh daemon service, `pam_loginuid` entry has to be set to optional in /etc/pam.d/sshd as described in the [official example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) for Ubuntu 13.10.

Was this entry optional for previous versions of Ubuntu? Did it even exist before Ubuntu 13.10?

What does setting `pam_loginuid` to `optional` mean, anyway?

Is my ssh configuration much less secure in this respect?

Comment: Link is now: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pam_loginuid` is used to set the `loginuid` audit attribute of a process when a user logs in through SSH, X, or anything like that. This attribute can then be used by the audit framework for various purposes.

However, setting this audit attributes requires some audit-related capabilities to be enabled; and by default, [Docker drops them](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/fec97e72db0ea6d1fcfd34ea2542a61d7b84e979/execdriver/lxc/init.go#L126), so the `audit_setloginuid` call will fail.

When the PAM module is configured to `required`, such failures are fatal (and PAM prevents the login from going on); while `optional` means "go on anyway".

I might be wrong, but I believe that while `pam_loginuid` is available in previous versions (I tested with 12.04) it wasn't enabled anyway; so that's why 13.10 and higher require this special setting.

Answer (score 2):

This investigation is too long for a comment. As [@jpetazzo indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21618386/1468366), this problem is likely due to lack of the `CAP_AUDIT_WRITE` capability. Which apparently affects some versions of Docker and Linux, but not others. So here I'll try to investigate the evolution of this.

- [#3015](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/3015) (2013-12-13, 0.7.2) introduced cap dropping for lxc daemon and included `AUDIT_WRITE` in the list of dropped capabilities
- [#5810](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/5810) (2014-05-16, 0.12.0) made container library drop all capabilities except for whitelisted ones
- [#6527](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/6527) (2014-06-19, 1.0.1) moved from blacklist to whitelist and didn't include `AUDIT_WRITE` in that
- [#7179](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/7179) (2014-07-24, 1.2.0) added the `AUDIT_WRITE` capability to a whitelist
- [#20662](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/20662) (2016-03-19, 1.11.0) moved files around so the setting is now in `oci/defaults_linux.go`

So it would seem as though all versions before 0.7.2 and also all versions since 1.2.0 should keep `CAP_AUDIT_WRITE`. As I'm seeing `pam_loginuid`-related problems with 1.12.5 there might be some other capability involved here.