# Issues running cron in Docker on different hosts

Tags: ubuntu, cron, docker, coreos

Im trying to get a docker container running to mange my cronjobs

im running a very simple cron as a test in a docker container using centOS 6.5 base

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "it works!" >> test.log
```

it works fine if the container is running on CoreOS host, however if I run the container on a ubuntu 13.10 host the cron is not executed. (I though the host did not effect what was running in the container)

both hosts are running docker 0.8

am I missing something obvious, or it this a bug?

thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391142/why-is-it-needed-to-set-pam-loginuid-to-its-optional-value-with-docker for an explanation why loginuid does not work.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**short answer**

add this line to your dockerfile

```
RUN sed -i '/session    required   pam_loginuid.so/c\#session    required   pam_loginuid.so' /etc/pam.d/crond
```

**the long answer**

from what I understand issue is related to differences in the kernal between CoreOS & Unbutu. this in-turn causes a pam security issue.

to figure it our first needed to turn on logging for cron (since we are in docker normal startup is not executed). run

```
service rsyslog start
service crond restart
```

the cron log had this error (located here /var/log/cron)

```
FAILED to open PAM security session (Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session)
```

so then I took a look at the security log, and it had this error (located here /var/log/secure)

```
pam_loginuid(crond:session): set_loginuid failed
```

some more googling and found I needed to modify my pam cond config (found here /etc/pam.d/crond)
edit this file and comment out the following line

```
#session    required   pam_loginuid.so
```

restart crond and all should be good

Comment: In my case I had to comment it out in `/etc/pam.d/cron`. Now it's working perfectly. Many Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I had an extra space in the file and the name was `/etc/pam.d/cron`, not `/etc/pam.d/crond`. Don't be surprised if `sed` does not work out of the box! Mine had this flavour:
```RUN sed -i '/session    required     pam_loginuid.so/c\#session    required     pam_loginuid.so' /etc/pam.d/cron```

Comment: Stackoverflow trims spaces :–( There is +1 space in front of `pam_loginuid.so`.

Comment: Another way to do this: `cat /etc/pam.d/cron | grep -v pam_loginuid.so > /etc/pam.d/cron2 && mv /etc/pam.d/cron2 /etc/pam.d/cron`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A better way to use sed is `sed -e '/pam_loginuid.so/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/pam.d/crond`

Comment: On a recent Debian release, to match any number of spaces in the config line, you can use `sed -E 's/^session\s+required\s+pam_loginuid.so$/#&/' -i /etc/pam.d/cron`

Answer (score 1):

the base Docker containers don't start services like cron - they only start what you specify in the ENTRYPOINT/CMD

some 'fatter' containers use things like supervisord to start services - but where possible, its more maintainable to separate services into different containers and share data using with volume containers, or --link

Comment: thanks for the suggestion SvenDowideit. My entrypoint was /bin/bash so I was testing normal command line. turned out to be a security issue with pam

Comment: Can you expand your answer on how. What do we need to put in entry point.

Answer (score 1):

@dwitz's answer is correct but I had to alter the `sed` command a bit to make it work for me on Ubuntu 16.04 within a docker container.

```
cat /etc/pam.d/cron |sed -e "s/required     pam_loginuid.so/optional     pam_loginuid.so/g" > /tmp/cron && mv /tmp/cron /etc/pam.d/cron
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I debug the cron:

```
$ apt-get install rsyslog
$ rsyslogd
$ service cron restart
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

And found `NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1` error in logs.

The solution was to put this in `entrypoint.sh`

```
touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/*
```

and boom!

Comment: Yo may need to run the container with `--privileged` option if you get the following error when running `rsyslogd`: `rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): Operation not permitted`