# cron job not running inside docker container on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron, docker

I have a simple Dockerfile as follows

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/test-cron

RUN chmod a+x /etc/cron.d/test-cron
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

and the content of `crontab` file is as simple as

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# empty line
```

When I run this on my local OS X machine (with docker-machine running), it works fine ("Hello world" is printed to log file every minute). However, when I try to run it on an Ubuntu machine, the cron job does not run (empty log file).

Here's the command I use to run the container

```
docker build -t crontest .
docker run --name cron crontest
```

I am not sure why this would be the case. I wonder if something is wrong with the Ubuntu box that I have (wrong time setting?). I have tried to restart that machine to no effect. I currently do have other docker containers running on the Ubuntu box and they're running fine.

Any suggestion on what I could do to debug/ fix this would be hugely appreciated.

EDIT:

After going inside the container (`docker exec -it cron /bin/bash`), I can verify that cron is running there:

```
root@a2ad451af8d9:/# ps -ef | grep cron
root         1     0  0 20:15 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
root         6     1  0 20:15 ?        00:00:00 cron
root         7     1  0 20:15 ?        00:00:00 tail -f /var/log/cron.log
root        25    11  0 20:21 ?        00:00:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @TinyGiant I can understand where you're coming from, but I think this is still a valid question, as it involves docker as well.

Comment: @TriNguyen did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue and was hoping to avoid a lengthy log investigation if you found a solution!

Comment: @DaveNovelli No I have not figured this out yet unfortunately :(

Comment: I got it working after looking real closely at the log. Two things I had to fix: 1) I'm using windows and my crontab file had CRLF instead of LF for the newline. The additional "^M" in the error message tipped me off. 2) After I fixed that, I had a new error that indicated a bad command. I realized that since I was using a user crontab file I didn't need the "root" at the beginning of the command. After that it worked like a charm. Big thanks to @Dzamo for the rsyslog tip!

Comment: Find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926465/issues-running-cron-in-docker-on-different-hosts Hooray!

Answer (score 41):

Install rsyslog inside the container with `apt-get install rsyslog` and launch it with the command `rsyslogd` before starting cron with `cron -L15` (maximum logging).  Then watch the file `/var/log/syslog` inside the container to see the cron daemon's own log output.  It will tell you if there was a problem parsing your crontab and it will, in your case, log an entry every minute similar to the below if it has registered and is trying to run your job.

`CRON[16]: (root) CMD (echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1)`

Comment: I had the same issue under docker container. Your solution worked for me, but I had to create syslog file under /var/log (touch /var/log/syslog) and change it's owner to syslog:adm (chown syslog:adm /var/log/syslog). And with cron speaking to syslog, I've discovered this: /usr/sbin/cron[2990]: (root) INSECURE MODE (mode 0600 expected) (crontabs/root). So I had to set correct permission mode 0600 (chmod 0600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root). After that, everything worked fine.

Comment: I also had this problem inside a Docker container. Installing `rsyslog`, starting it and running `cron -L15` magically made my jobs run (I didn't even check the logs). So my cron job command had no errors.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue, specifically with Ubuntu 14.04. To debug, I tried running cron in foreground, and found it to emit `System error` messages while trying to run the scheduled jobs.

Apparently, its a known issue with `--net=host` parameter (ref: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5899). I tried passing `--pid=host` as suggested, and with that, the cron jobs started running fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a backup script called `backup.sh` that I copied to `/etc/cron.daily`.
The script was not called properly.

To make it to I had to rename to the to just `backup` without the `.sh`

So for me `ls -l /etc/cron.daily` had the following output:

```
root@0989a35b8f94:/# ls -l /etc/cron.daily
total 24
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1474 Sep 13 16:47 apt-compat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root   45 Nov  9 11:18 dobackup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1597 Feb 22  2017 dpkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4125 Mar  2  2016 exim4-base
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  249 May 17 11:59 passwd
```

---

To test/analyse this I used the following approach:

I looked up the crontab file `cat /etc/crontab` showing the following line for the daily cronjobs:

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

I then isolated my backup script into a dedicated folder:

```
mkdir /etc/cron.test
mv /etc/cron.daily/dobackup /etc/cron.test
```

Then by running

```
test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.test)
```

and using `ps auxf` on a different terminal showed me that the jobs now is running. You can also verify that it breaks when renaming to the `.sh` version:

```
mv /etc/cron.test/dobackup /etc/cron.test/dobackup.sh
test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.test)
```

It then exists immediately, so no job is run.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I `COPY` a file it created a secondary hard link (it may be a Windows thing).

What I had to do was make sure the file was created inside a running container.

```
FROM mysql:5.7
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y anacron
COPY crontab /tmp/crontab

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD (cat /tmp/crontab > /etc/cron.d/hello-cron ) && cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed in debian recently: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=726661 and in Ubuntu Wily (15.10).

> As a workaround you can try commenting the module pam_loginuid.so
>   inside /etc/pam.d/cron and restart cron (or the docker container).