# crontab not working on Centos Docker container

Tags: python, docker, centos, cron

I am trying to run a few python scripts through **Crontab in Centos docker container**, but nothing I have tried is working.

Firstly I installed cron:

```
yum install vixie-cron
```

Then I ran it as a service:

```
/etc/init.d/crond start
```

(I also ran `/sbin/service crond` start because some answers to related questions suggested so)

`ps aux | grep cron` shows:

```
root     16917  0.0  0.0  23288  1252 ?        Ss   18:53   0:00 crond                                                                                
root     16929  0.0  0.0   9720   836 pts/0    S+   18:55   0:00 grep cron
```

`crontab -l` looks like:

```
0 17 1 * * /root/proj/env/bin/python /root/proj/files/frontend/file1.py > /var/log/cron.log                                                      

0 9 4 * * /root/proj/env/bin/python /root/proj/files/frontend/file2.py > /var/log/cron.log                                                      

0 17 15 * * /root/proj/env/bin/python /root/proj/files/frontend/file3.py > /var/log/cron.log                                                     

0 9 18 * * /root/proj/env/bin/python /root/proj/files/frontend/file4.py > /var/log/cron.log                                                     

0 14 * * * /root/proj/env/bin/python /root/proj/files/frontend/file5.py > /var/log/cron.log                                               

0 8 * * * /root/proj/env/bin/python /root/proj/files/frontend/file6.py > /var/log/cron.log                                                  

* * * * * echo 'Check!!' > /var/log/cron.log
```

All python scripts and the cron.log file have permission `777`
The last entry in crontab is just to check if anything is getting written to the log file... but nothing is being written there..

Any idea how to solve this?

PS: I looked through a ton of related QnAs but none of them helped.

Some answers had suggested writing to `/etc/crontab`.. so I even made the entry: `* * * * * root echo 'Blah' > var/log/cron.log`  there.. but to no effect :(

Comment: is it normal that you have so many spaces after every line? Also, what user are you using for these crons? What do you get if you say `service crond status`?

Comment: @fedorqui: I am running them as root because AFAIK the crontab user is the user who executed the command crontab -e...

`service crond status` shows `crond (pid  16917) is running... `

Comment: OK. Not sure what is your last line, though. It does not need `root` as user, `* * * * * echo "hi" >> /tmp/test.log` should suffice.

Comment: added `* * * * * echo "hi" >> /tmp/test.log` as well.. that's not working either

Comment: Give it a minute : ) It is strange. Did you clean the trailing spaces in the crontab by the way?

Comment: it seems to be a copy paste issue, in vim those trailing spaces arent present.. and still no entries in  `/tmp/test.log`

Comment: Can you say `crontab -l | cat - -vet`? (exactly like this) to see if some weird characters appear in the crontab?

Comment: @fedorqui: it returns `0 17 1 * * /root/proj/env/bin/python /root/loom/loom/frontend/open_upload.py > /var/log/cron.log$                                                     
$` and so on for the other lines... what does the $ at the end mean? newline character?

Comment: Yes, it is newline, so it means the file is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a day wasted in suboptimal Googling and experimentation, the answer to this conundrum was **commenting out** the following line in the file `/etc/pam.d/crond` (and then running  `service crond restart`):

```
session required pam_loginuid.so
```

This is because of some Docker-Centos security issue. I don't have further details on why this works. (Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926465/issues-running-cron-in-docker-on-different-hosts) for details.)

Also, troubleshooting this made me realize a few gotchas which **might** be useful:

- Check that you have crond running as a service (if not, use
  `/etc/init.d/crond start`)
- Each line in your crontab should be followed be a newline character
- Your scripts and log file should have suitable write/execute
  permissions
- crontab file shouldn't have weird Windows environment characters
  (like ^M)
- In some rare cases, crond might have different time zone than your
  system
- Also check `/etc/cron.allow and /etc/cron.deny` files to verify who
  can add/edit cron jobs

May **your** day be invested in more fruitful pursuits, stranger.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend run cron under host and run command inside the container

example:

```
0 17 1 * * /usr/bin/docker exec container_name /root/proj/env/bin/python /root/proj/files/frontend/file1.py > /var/log/cron.log
```