# Cron in the same container works locally but fails in cluster

Tags: docker, cron, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a super simple container with cron scheduled:

```
* * * * * root /bin/bash /alive.sh
```

alive.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/echo "I'm alive"
/bin/echo $(/bin/date) >> /tmp/alive.log
```

I build the docker image locally and run it:

```
docker build -t orian/crondemo:v0 .
docker run --rm -it --name crondemo orian/crondemo:v0
```

And after a minute or so I can check that a new file is being created:

```
docker exec crondemo ls /tmp
```

The I tag and push the image to Google Container Registry:

```
TAG=eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/crondemo:v0
docker tag orian/crondemo:v0 $TAG
kubectl docker -- push $TAG
```

Starting a pod manually:

```
kubectl run crondemo --image=$TAG --replicas=1 --restart=Never
```

And verifying that it works:

```
kubectl exec crondemo ls /tmp
```

And here is a problem, a `/tmp/alive.log` file is not being written to. Where is the problem?

I've prepared a repo with sample: https://github.com/orian/k8s-cron-demo

#### Notice

- I've also tested overwriting `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` but it didn't solve the problem.
- I'm using docker image: `openjdk:8-jre`. Before switching I used `alpine` and `crond`. It's seemed to work then.

#### Edit2 - found (this is crazy):

- https://forums.docker.com/t/running-cronjob-in-debian-jessie-container/17527/2
- [Issues running cron in Docker on different hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926465/issues-running-cron-in-docker-on-different-hosts)
- [Why is it needed to set `pam_loginuid` to its `optional` value with docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391142/why-is-it-needed-to-set-pam-loginuid-to-its-optional-value-with-docker)

Answer (score 3):

I've followed a https://stackoverflow.com/a/21928878/436754 on enabling logs.

Running: `/var/log/syslog`

```
May  4 12:33:05 crondemo rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="14" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
May  4 12:33:05 crondemo rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log(/proc/kmsg): Operation not permitted.
May  4 12:33:05 crondemo rsyslogd-2145: activation of module imklog failed [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]
May  4 12:33:08 crondemo cron[38]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
May  4 12:33:08 crondemo cron[39]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
May  4 12:33:08 crondemo cron[39]: (*system*) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/crontab)
May  4 12:33:08 crondemo cron[39]: (*system*crondemo) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/cron.d/crondemo)
May  4 12:33:08 crondemo cron[39]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
May  4 12:34:01 crondemo cron[39]: (*system*) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/crontab)
May  4 12:34:01 crondemo cron[39]: (*system*crondemo) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/cron.d/crondemo)
```

This made me Google for `cron "NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1"` and I've found: https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/198

The workaround is to modify a `Dockerfile` to overwrite the cron file on start instead being mounted by Docker.

- Dockerfile `COPY cronfile /cronfile`
- `docker-entrypoint.sh`: `cp /cronfile /etc/cron.d/crondemo`

A branch with workaround: https://github.com/orian/k8s-cron-demo/tree/with-rsyslog